# Reason of enabling voting after the question gets closed

Tags: discussion, voting, closed-questions

Question scores show how a question is good or suitable to a specific site, or it is not suitable or has poor quality.

But there is something I wonder. After a question got closed, it still can receive upvotes/downvotes.

Downvoting means, a question is either not suitable or have poor quality or is duplicate. Downvoting a poor question, for example, shows the question owner and other users that there is something wrong about the question.  But after the question got closed, users can still downvote it. Since the question is already closed, what is the reason of letting it got more downvotes? Both users and the question owner already know that it has low quality and needed to be improved (if it is possible to reopen it after improvement). Close reason is also written under the question.

Similarly, a user with enough reputation may vote to reopen the question, if he had enough reputation to do so. Also, AFAIK there is no way to see how many upvotes/downvotes a question had received after it had closed. So, that also do not reflect the community thought about the closure of the question.

So I wonder, what is the logic behind letting closed questions still being able to vote?